# How to show/hide a button in ReactNative?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, button, react-redux, redux-toolkit

I am trying to code an alarm app and I would like to hide a button if the alarm is enabled and show it if the alarm is disabled so the user can enable the alarm again. Disabling and enabling the alarm happens on the alarm screen, however the home screen shows if the alarm has been enabled/disabled in the alarm screen as well. The home screen is where the button to switch the alarm back on is located.

I get the state of the alarm through redux toolkit in switch.js:

```
    import { createSlice } from '@reduxjs/toolkit';

    const initialStateValue = {
        active: true
    }

    const switchSlice = createSlice({
        name: 'alarm',
        initialState: initialStateValue,
        reducers: {
            toggleOn: (state = initialStateValue) => {
                state.active = true;
            },
            toggleOff: (state = initialStateValue) => {
                state.active = false;
            },
        }
    });

    export const {toggleOn, toggleOff} = switchSlice.actions;
    export default switchSlice.reducer;
```

In the main screen I have this so far:

```
    import { useDispatch, useSelector } from 'react-redux';
    import { toggleOn, toggleOff } from '../components/switch';

    function Home({navigation}) {

      const alarmOff = require('../images/Alarm_off.png');
      const alarmDisabled = require('../images/Alarm_off_disabled.png');

      const switchValue = useSelector((state) => state.alarm.active);
      const dispatch = useDispatch();

      function activateAlarmHandler() {
        if (switchValue == true) {
           dispatch(toggleOff());
        } else {
           dispatch(toggleOn());
        }
      }

      return (
         <View style={globalStyles.containerMainHome}>
            <ImageBackground 
              source={switchValue ? alarmOff : alarmDisabled}
            >
              <Pressable 
                style={({pressed}) => pressed 
                  ? [globalStyles.button, styles.pressed] 
                  : globalStyles.button}
                onPress={activateAlarmHandler}
              >
                <Text style={globalStyles.textButton}>Activate Alarm</Text>
              </Pressable>
            </ImageBackground>
         </View>
      );
    }
```

The function 'activateAlarmHandler' works really well, I can activate and deactivate the alarm from the home screen and the alarm screen gets it. But how do I hide the Button (Preassable) if switchValue is true?

Comment: You want to hide the `<Pressable />` if `switchValue` is true?

Comment: Yes, exactly! Sorry if that wasn't clear.

Comment: You can simply wrap the pressable component with a condition `!switchValue && <Pressable />`

Comment: Thank you! Can you tell me how to do that? Putting '!switchValue &&' infront of <Pressable> and </Pressable> doesn't work.

Comment: I added it in curly braces and it works! Thank you.